# Solving a Recurrence Relation with Characteristic Roots: is my algebra bad, or is it something else?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am having a considerable amount of trouble solving this problem. I have shown my work below and am wondering if somebody can show me where I have messed up. I have been working on this for a few hours and would appreciate the help.

**The question**

> Solve $a_0$ $=$ $1$, $a_1$ $=$ $3$, and $a_{n-1}$ +$6a_{n-2}$ for $n$ $\geq$ $2$.

---

**My Work**

$$a_n-a_{n-1}-6a_{n-2}=0$$
$$r^{2}-r-6=0$$
$$(r-3)(r+2)$$
$$r=3, r=-2$$
then, $$\alpha(3)^{n}+\beta(-2)^{n}=a_n$$
and 
$$a_0=\alpha(3)^{0}+\beta(-2)^{0}=1$$
thus,$$\alpha +\beta=1$$

and $$a_1=\alpha(3)^{1}+\beta(-2)^{1}=3$$

By simplifying, $$-3(\alpha+\beta=1)$$
$$3\alpha-2\beta=3$$
$$\beta=0, \alpha=1$$

---

I know this is *not* the case. I have tried switching around the $-2$ and $3$ in the equation, but I can't seem to get the answer *that* way either. I end up with coefficients equalling $-\frac{1}{5}$ and $\frac{4}{5}$ or something to that effect. I am struggling on this problem and would appreciate guidance.

Comment: `I know this is not the case` How do you know that?

Comment: Having that $\beta$ $=$ $0$  doesn't even work with our sample case, $a_1$.

Comment: $a_0=3^0=1, a_1=3^1=3$, so what's not working?

Comment: Wouldn't the equation then become $a_n$ $=$ $3\alpha^{n}$ , since the $\beta$ coefficient makes that value $0$? Are you suggesting I have the correct solution?

Comment: You set $a_n = \alpha 3^n + \beta (-2)^n$ and found $\alpha=1, \beta=0$ so $a_n=3^n$. And, yes, that's the correct solution.

Comment: Ah..ever just *trick* yourself out and do bad algebra? I would have thought I'm beyond this...but clearly not...now the question is do I delete, or keep for whoever gave me +1 on the question....hmmmmm.

Comment: @Prime `solve ... and a_n−1 + 6a_n−2` At least fix the question, since it's missing something here ;-)

Comment: @WillJagy this is probably what I should do. Checking $3\alpha^{n}$ with more than just the given statements might prove to be useful here.

Comment: @dxiv well, that's literally exactly verbatim what the book says haha.

Comment: **WAIT** is @dxiv suggestting that every input yields....$3$?

Comment: @WillJagy There seems to be a problem wwith my solution then. As I originally. Thought. $1^{n}$  $\forall$ $\mathbb{N}$ $=$ $1$

Comment: @Prime `every input yields....3?` I never suggested that, please read more carefully. All I wrote is that $\,a_n=3^n\,$ is the correct solution in *this* case i.e. when $\,a_0=1,a_1=3\,$. And btw $\,3^n \ne 3\,$.

Comment: $a_3$ $=$ $27$ . Unfortunately, $3$ $\alpha^{n}$ does not equal this.

Comment: There is little point to solving recursively from here on out, considering I do not have a closed for to check. Anyone want to try an answer? Not interested in things that only work in specific cases. Such an effort is moot.

Comment: You keep writing $\,3 \alpha^n\,$ instead of $\,3^n\,$. This doesn't come from anywhere in the question you posted, and it's been pointed out several times already that it is $\,3^n\,$, *not* $\,3 \alpha^n\,$.

Comment: Well that alpha is supposed to be a coefficient, even if invisible. Right?

Comment: Right, and $\alpha \cdot 3^n = 3^n$ when $\alpha=1$. I suggest you step back for a second and re-read all the comments more carefully.

Comment: @dxiv I apologize for being hard headed. We are placing the alpha in different places. As it is a coefficient, you seem to be right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80640/discussion-between-prime-and-dxiv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the many comments under the main question, OP's solution is correct, and $\,a_n=3^n\,$ is indeed the correct result. Step by step...

> **The question**
>
> Solve $a_0$ $=$ $1$, $a_1$ $=$ $3$, and $a_{n-1}$ +$6a_{n-2}$ for $n$ $\geq$ $2$.

Presumably, the latter part should read $\,\color{red}{a_n=}a_{n-1} + 6a_{n-2}\,$ for the recurrence to be well defined.

> **My Work**
>
> $$a_n-a_{n-1}-6a_{n-2}=0$$
>
> $$r^{2}-r-6=0$$
> $$(r-3)(r+2)$$
> $$r=3, r=-2$$

Correct. The given relation is a [linear homogeneous recurrence with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients), and one standard method to solve it is using [the associated characteristic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation#Solution_of_homogeneous_case).

> $$\alpha(3)^{n}+\beta(-2)^{n}=a_n$$

Correct, $\,a_n=\alpha \cdot 3^n + \beta \cdot (-2)^n$ where $\,\alpha,\beta\,$ are constants to be determined from the initial conditions.

> $$\beta=0, \alpha=1$$

Correct. Substituting back, it follows that $\,a_n=\alpha \cdot 3^n + \beta \cdot (-2)^n = 1 \cdot 3^n + 0 \cdot (-2)^n = 3^n\,$.

> I know this is *not* the case.

This in fact the only wrong statement of the post. It ***is*** the case that $\,a_n=3^n\,$ is the correct solution. For verification:

- $a_0=3^0=1\,$ satisfies the first initial condition;
- $a_1=3^1=3\,$ satisfies the second initial condition;
- $a_n=3^n=3 \cdot 3^{n-1} = 3^{n-1} + 2 \cdot 3^{n-1} = 3^{n-1} + 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3^{n-2} = a_{n-1}+6 a_{n-2}$ satisfies the recurrence relation for $\,n \ge 2\,$.

Comment: Well, we already discussed that it wasn't the case. I am thankful for the correction and summative and comprehensive answer (step by step, indeed!) for others to view and learn as well. +1.

Comment: @Prime Thanks. It was getting hard to follow in the comments, so I thought I'd post the write-up as an answer to take the question off the un-answered queue.